# Akka actors and aroundReceive() method

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I'm trying to learn Akka (with Java) and understand some code. I have seen something like this, this method signature in a Actor class :

```
@Override
public void aroundReceive(PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive, Object msg)
```

I've never heard of that method before and don't understand it. What is the purpose of that method ? Where does this `PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit>` receive argument comes from ? I thought it was up to the programmer to implement receive object.

Comment: Anton, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for `PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit>`, the `receive` function in an (untyped) actor is an instance of that (this is made abundantly clear in the Scala API, and somewhat less-so in the Java API).

An Actor implementing this (typically via a Scala mixin or extending an abstract class which overrides it) would take the `receive` function from the actor implemented by the programmer and intercept calls to certain messages (e.g. timing messages) or do pre-/post-processing of messages which are passed onto the given `receive`.

`PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit>` basically means:

- this is a function which doesn't promise to have a result for any particular input; it's the responsibility of the caller to check beforehand (`isDefinedAt`) if the function will have a result or to accept that the function will throw an exception. (`PartialFunction`: a function which is not defined over the entirety of its domain)
- `Object` (or in Scala terms `Any` (technically `AnyRef`, but autoboxing lets us forget that for a moment)): the function can theoretically accept anything
- `BoxedUnit` indicates that the function returns no useful result (`Unit` in Scala is like `void` in Java, but is actually an object (a singleton to be precise)).

(to some extent `PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit>` is the type which tells us and the compiler the least information possible).

Answer (score 0):

First, I am using Akka in Scala, and not in Java. I hope this answer will give you a lead.
In Scala, this method is `@InternalApi`. The docs of that in Scala is:

> Marks APIs that are considered internal to Akka and may change at any point in time without any
> warning.
> For example, this annotation should be used when the Scala {@code private[akka]} access
> restriction is used, as Java has no way of representing this package restricted access and such
> methods and classes are represented as {@code public} in byte-code

One purpose of this method is to wrap the receive method with custom behaviour. You can see an example for that in the [Timers](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Timers.scala#L41) trait.